# One Font Awesome Icon Specifically has stopped displaying on my wordpress site

Tags: html, wordpress, icons, font-awesome, display

I have a site with a number of font awesome icons on a page. They all loaded correctly until recently, I noticed today that the handshake icon has stopped displaying the element is `##.fa-handshake-o.fa.vc_icon_element-icon`. I have tried replacing it with other FA icons and they display fine. Only the handshake icon has stopped.

Can anyone help me with a fix to get it to display again?

I can provide any more info if needed. Thank you.

Comment: <i  class="fa fa-handshake-o"></i> like this you are displaying in template?

Comment: I actually added it using WPBakery pagebuilder, and it is a shortcode like this: 

`[vc_icon icon_fontawesome="fa fa-handshake-o" color="custom" size="xl" align="center" custom_color="#fb6706"]`

Also I have tried changing it to handshake without the o and it just makes the element disappear altogether.

Comment: try using new fontawesome cdn

Comment: The font-awesome stylesheet in the theme is font-awesome.min.css which is identical to that stylesheet.

Comment: I'm not actually sure how to implement a CDN as a stylesheet source in wordpress. Do you know how that would be done to override the font-awesome.min.css ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: i mean use latest version of font.awesome.css , sometimes icons will be deprecated and it will broke few icons , you can get latest version of font.awesome from fontawesome official website, try using that

Comment: For posterity... The problem was a plugin called "Polls" inserting an older version of FA.